# Errors importing data to SQL from FileMaker

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odbc, filemaker

I am creating SSIS Package to import data into SQL Server 2019 from FileMaker 19.2.2. I have set up 32bit ODBC to connect to Layout and can access the source system in SSIS Source Editor and view sample data without issue.
I've mapped my ODBC Source to my OLE DB SQL Server Destination and inserted a Data Conversion step and am able to load just one of my four test columns.  Keep getting data type errors like the below.

Has anyone successfully created SSIS Package to pull data from FileMaker?  This shouldn't be that hard.  I am hoping someone can help.

> [OLE DB Destination [436]] Error: An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "NameFirst" column. The binding status was "DT_NTEXT". The data flow column type is "DBBINDSTATUS_UNSUPPORTEDCONVERSION". The conversion from the OLE DB type of "DBTYPE_IUNKNOWN" to the destination column type of "DBTYPE_WVARCHAR" might not be supported by this provider.

> [OLE DB Destination [436]] Error: An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "NameLast" column. The binding status was "DT_NTEXT".

> [OLE DB Destination [436]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification".
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid date format".

Here's source Metadata I am trying to load.

[enter image description here][1]

```
Name    Data Type   Precision   Scale   Length  Code Page   Sort Key Position   Comparison Flags    Source Component
Created DT_DBTIMESTAMP  0   0   0   0   0       ODBC Source
KeyEmployee DT_TEXT 0   0   0   1252    0       ODBC Source
Modified    DT_DBTIMESTAMP  0   0   0   0   0       ODBC Source
NameFirst   DT_TEXT 0   0   0   1252    0       ODBC Source
NameLast    DT_TEXT 0   0   0   1252    0       ODBC Source
EmployeeID  DT_TEXT 0   0   0   1252    0       ODBC Source
EmploymentDate  DT_DBDATE   0   0   0   0   0       ODBC Source
```

Comment: I have been able to perform workaround to get data from FileMaker into a .txt file using SSIS but still facing same issue with converting unicode DT_Text to varchar(max) on import to SQL Server.
Anyone have suggestions how to overcome that SSIS import issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after many trial and error attempts I was able to extract all the FileMaker data into a text file. I then created an additional control flow to load the text file into the SQL database by creating a derived column to concatenate First and Last names and adding data conversion the derive Employee column. On the SQL side I converted columns to nvarchar(50).  In some cases with the text data I had to use nvarchar(max) - again, required a good bit of trial and error. For numeric columns I defined them as float.  The datetime columns needed no special treatment.
I hope this might be helpful to anyone else who may be having difficulty extracting data from FileMaker.